# Magento extension upload error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have tried installing many free and paid plugins but every time I am getting this error

CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars
Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
Invalid stability
Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM
Invalid channel URL
Empty authors section
Empty package contents section

Is there any solution for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting error from Magento connect, you can directly install the extension by downloading the extension zip and copy extension files in magento root directory.

you can download extension directly from the following site:

`http://www.tangkoko.com/direct-download-magento-extension/`

Paste magento connect key there.

Hope this help !!

Comment: It works when I using same version downloaded from tangkoko.com Thanks Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

The magento modules downloaded from the magento connect have package.xml file with it, which verifies the module's whether it was downloaded from Magento connect or not.

All Magento versions > 1.5 support the extension key of magento connect version 2.0. While selecting key from Magento connect, please check the extension key must be of magento connect version 2.0.

[image]

I hope, it will solve this will help you. :)

Comment: I am using magento 1.7 Thank you for explanation